# Trying To Access A Wordpress Site Over The Internet

Tags: wordpress, apache, webserver, permalinks, connectivity

I have a wordpress site on the Ubuntu computer that I am using as a webserver. I have the wordpress system installed in /var/www/html. I have created pages which display nicely from any computer, tablet or handheld within my lan environment.

I am going crazy trying to access my website from the internet. Can anybody please help?

- I have a noip address and a BTHub which allows me to set up dynamic dns to inform my noip account automatically when the ip changes and this works fine.
- I have set up port forwarding for http and https to the computer hosting my wordpress site
- I have tried assigning DMZ to my wordpress hosting computer
- I have made sure I own the wordpress folders and files within them
- my LAMP installed without a hitch and over the LAN access is no problem with one exception - I can only use the default permalinks or wordpress can not find my pages - no idea why? I had to cut wordpress into var/www/html as it initially went into www and could not be found
- I have spent DAYS with this! It is a part of a bigger project where I want to run some projects across the internet. I dispair that if I cant get a simple wordpress site to work that my projects are doomed! lol.
- When I try to access my site from another location across the internet, I get the first page, but without the media picture that should be on it. When I try to change pages I get the not found message. I also get the initial page without a style sheet in some instances. I have no clue about how to fix this. I took up Linux about three months ago, having been a windows and OSx man for years. I am in love, but have a steep learning curve!

It looks like a location issue or a WAN address issue or something I cant figure out!

I would appreciate any help that anyone out there can give me.

Eric

Comment: Can you share your Apache config?  Also, have you checked your Apache logs to see if they have any more details about the 404 errors?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. I have just this moment sorted it out. I read up the permalinks wiki thoroughly and I found out how to change the URLs from within the wp- files in the theme I was using. After a few refreshes it now works. I will post up a how-to for any others who may be experiencing the same frustration.